# business English

Tags: vocabulary

I wasted around three years studying general English courses without any progress in my writing in my formal mail.

I have to send 10 emails per day so I spend a long time searching for similar mail to copy.

Could you please advise me on how can I improve my skills in buiness English.

Do you know a book or website that can help me?

Comment: @snailcar I disagree. It is not a matter of opinion whether there is a hornbook covering all or even a majority of possible emails related to business in the UK, North America, India, and Pakistan. If there is such a hornbook, please name it. If you think this question deserves closing (I do not), the reason should be "to broad." Personally, I think this question indicates a common mistake among learners, namely that English can be written by formula.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Questions like this are out of scope for the site. That doesn’t make them bad questions, or mean that it wouldn’t help people if someone shared their advice. It just means that this format doesn’t support this sort of discussion very well, and it was never intended to.

Comment: @Jeff - I think this more or less straddles the fuzzy boundary between "too broad" and "primarily opinion-based"; however, the system allows us to only pick one or the other.  The last part of this question reads like a "What's your favorite ____?" question, and those are pretty clearly [off-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @Coleen and JR Without being argumentative, I can see that boundaries frequently need to be fuzzy and that this is a difficult question to address in this format. I agree that inquiring about a reference work implies asking about a reference work that is reliable, and judgments about reliability are technically opinions. What is not subjective is if a work is widely cited. So the question can be answered objectivel. (Of course, I doubt there is such a work.) My primary issue here is that pushing the opinion button without an amplifying comment is not likely to help the OP revise the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent 54 years in an active business career, including the last ten years on a sizable bank's board. The English that has consistently been used in every business where I have been an employee or a director or an active stockholder is standard American English.

There are of course words with technical meanings used in business, but those meanings tend to be specific to an industry or specialty. For example, accountants share a technical vocabulary across industries, and few people outside the steel industry have a clue what a blooming mill does. But those words are not in general use in business. What is called IT in the U.S. is a particularly dense jungle of necessary technical vocabulary, jargon, and acronyms. And any aspect of business that is heavily entangled with the law tends to adopt the legal terms of art that are directly relevant. Some bankers and lawyers know what a holder in due course is, but 99.9% of the business world is blissfully in ignorance of the term.

If you are looking for a book that will teach you the argot of every trade and every craft in every English-speaking country, there probably is no such thing. You need to say what line of business or what specialty you need to communicate about and in what country.

PS The whole point about email is that people use it informally despite being told that doing so is bad practice. If you are looking for a hornbook on standard email, there is no such thing. If you write emails in standard English, are complete and exact in your substance, and are reasonably polite in your tone, your email will be better than that of most native speakers.

Comment: thanks a lot, Jeff for your valuable response. i look for reference to improve my general business English which is not related to a specific field . for example check the below way of writing that i wsih to follow it for example " I have added some of our personnel in the mailing list. I will appreciate if you can ensure that all xxxx personnel copied in this email will be copied for all email communications from henceforth".

Comment: I am going to give you an unsatisfactory answer. Your example has at least 1 minor error in usage and has, in my opinion, several moderate defects in style. It is, however, essentially grammatical and so quite comprehensible, but it sounds odd. You could ask about this example as a question, but it too would probably be closed because this site does not do proofreading and, correctly, deems questions about style to be based on opinion.  However, the comment itself shows more serious lapses. All of these could be addressed by improvements in English generally: they are not peculiar to business.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind support and valuable advice.